# OCI runtime create failed: systemd cgroup flag passed, but systemd support for managing cgroups is not available

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, virtual-machine, docker, cgroups

On installing docker when I run the `sudo docker run hello-world`, I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
systemd cgroup flag passed, but systemd support for managing cgroups is not 
available: unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I tried looking into the error but couldn't find anything similar. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue by upgrading to 16.04LTS [earlier I was using 14.04LTS].

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem recently. My system infos are as follows:

- CentOS 7 64bit
- Kernel version: `3.10.xxx`

I tried these methods below:

1. Upgrade kernel version to `5.xxx` (**Failed to run `docker run hello-world`** with the same problems below)
2. Reinstall docker by docker installation reference(The running docker whose version was 18.xx, was installed manually from docker-18.xx.tgz)

After finishing point 1 & point 2, `docker run hello-world` works.

The reason why this problem occurs: kernel issues about cgroup driver(`systemd`).

As for the detail of the reason, it was beyond me.

Just share some ideas that may works with guys who met this problem.